# Iterate over keys in map from largest length to smallest length

Tags: c++, iteration, c++20

I am trying to iterate over all keys in a map. I have this code:

```
map<string, array<string, 3>> dat;
array<string, 3> dt({ "var","TEXT","" });
dat["atest"] = dt;
array<string, 3> at({ "var","DATA","" });
dat["testplusalot"] = at;
array<string, 3> t({ "var","NONE","" });
dat["testalot"] = t;
for (const auto& p : dat) {
    cout << p.first << endl;
}
```

I want it to say

```
testplusalot
testalot 
atest
```

but I get

```
atest
testalot
testplusalot
```

how could I do this.

Comment: Do you know how to define a custom comparator class for `std::map`, the optional third parameter to the `std::map` template, and how to use it?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No, I'm new to C++.

Comment: If that's the case, then where does this programming task come from? This is done by implementing a custom comparator, so I would expect that you would get this kind of a task in a chapter of your C++ textbook that explains how to do that. Is there something ***specific*** in your textbook's explanation, where this programing task must be from, that's unclear?

Comment: @greatusername -- What is the criteria if the strings are the same length?  Which one is printed first?  And if you are not sure, shouldn't this question have been raised to the person(s) who gave you this assignment?  It seems like an obvious issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't really care. It can be ordered in any way if the strings are the same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to order the keys by length, and then if the lengths are the same, order them alphabetically (the simplest fall-back ordering), then the following can be done:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

// Create a type that describes the sort order
struct strCompare 
{
    bool operator()(const std::string& Left, const std::string& Right) const 
    {
        // Sort by length 
        if ( Left.length() != Right.length() )
            return Left.length() > Right.length();

       // Fall back to string < ordering
        return Left < Right;            
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::array<std::string, 3>, strCompare> dat;
    std::array<std::string, 3> dt({ "var","TEXT","" });
    dat["atest"] = dt;
    std::array<std::string, 3> at({ "var","DATA","" });
    dat["testplusalot"] = at;
    std::array<std::string, 3> t({ "var","NONE","" });
    dat["testalot"] = t;
    std::array<std::string, 3> t2({ "var","NONE","" });
    dat["testblot"] = t2;
    for (const auto& p : dat) {
        std::cout << p.first << std::endl;
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
testplusalot
testalot
testblot
atest
```

The `strCompare` is a type that has an overloaded `<` that determines the key sort criteria.

Then the creation of the `std::map` requires that you specify the sort ordering in the [third template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

```
std::map<std::string, std::array<std::string, 3>, strCompare> dat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the map like it is shown in the code snippet below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <map>

//...

    auto descending = []( const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2 )
    {
        auto n1 = s1.size(), n2 = s2.size();
        return std::tie( n2, s1 ) < std::tie( n1, s2 );
    };

    std::map<std::string, std::array<std::string, 3>, decltype( descending )> dat( descending );

    dat =
    {
        { "test", { "var","TEXT","" } },
        { "testplusalot", { "var","DATA","" } },
        { "testalot", { "var","NONE","" } }
    };

    for (const auto &p : dat)
    {
        std::cout << p.first << '\n';
    }
```

Its output is

```
testplusalot
testalot
test
```

Comment: Only because it just so happens that the reverse-alphabetical order coincides with the "by largest length" order. The OP will be very disappointed when other data fails with this solution.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Maybe it is what he wants. All the keys he showed are prefixed with the word "test".

Comment: I can't think of an alternative interpretation of "largest length to smallest length".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik If he will say that it is not what he needs I will remove the answer. No problem.:)

Comment: This wont let you add two different strings of the same length into the map.

Answer (score -1):

Add **std::greated** as a Compare function in std::map (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater).

[image]

```
#include <map>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::array<std::string, 3>, std::greater<std::string>> dat;
    
    std::array<std::string, 3> dt({ "var","TEXT","" });
    dat["test"] = dt;

    std::array<std::string, 3> at({ "var","DATA","" });
    dat["testplusalot"] = at;

    std::array<std::string, 3> t({ "var","NONE","" });
    dat["testalot"] = t;

    for (const auto& p : dat) {
        std::cout << p.first << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output will be:

```
testplusalot
testalot
test
```

PS, this code will also return

```
testplusalot
testalot
atest
```

for the [testplusalot, testalot, atest] keys.

Comment: That would be alphabetized. I want it in the same order *regardless* of the first letter. The keys will not always start with `test`.

Comment: Your answer is correct in that it adds a compare function, but code-only answers are not helpful to others that may read this answer later. A short paragraph explaining what `std::greater` is and why you use it instead of another custom comparator would make the answer more useful. A link to the topic in cppreference.com (e.g. [std::map<Key,T,Compare,Allocator>::value_compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/value_compare) also adds to the usefulness of your answer.

Comment: If you want the same order of the elements as you added them into a container the std::map isn't the best choice. It sorts the elements under the hood.

Comment: They don't want the same order, they want the elements in the map to be in order of longest string to shortest string.  This does not do that.  It has them in lexicographical order.  With this code, `"z"` would be printed first if it was added to map, even though it is the shortest string.

Comment: Oh, ok. It wasn't in the question.